# Xcode 4.3 "Expected identifier or '('"

Tags: iphone, xcode, sdk

So I have just created a new project and it is showing errors before I even had touched the file, Im very new to Xcode but here is my code:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface "ViewController.h"

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
    } else {
        return YES;
    }
}

@end
```

And it is shown the error that is in the titel at " @interface "ViewController.h" "

Comment: @interface ViewController, or you can just delete interface part, and un-comment #import "ViewController.h".

Comment: Don't forget to mark the correct answer with the √ button!

Answer (score 8):

That is the error. You want `@interface ViewController`.

Comment: @Alexander Akers That didnt work thats why i tested the " thing

Comment: That's because it's expecting a class extension. Try either removing that section or putting `()` after the `ViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

It is

```
@interface ViewController


@end
```

You have to use `" "` when you are importing an header, `<>` a framework.

`@interface` is an objective-c object, in this case a class, so you don't need the `""`.